# apply css to only 1st unknown element of div

Tags: css, css-selectors

**I want to apply margin top:15px to only 1st element of this div**

I am pulling ckeditor data from database
that is why 1st element is unpredictable

This is my div structure ,

```
<div class="ckeditordata">

//1st element is unknown
//can be <p>, <ul>, <ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `:first-child`.

```
.ckeditordata > :first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/1re2p8sp/2/

Comment: `.ckeditordata > :first-child` will be better I think. As it can be `<ul>` and the like

Comment: yeh that is great answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use css `>` child selector with `:nth-child(1)` to apply css only for 1st child like this:

```css
.ckeditordata > *:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ckeditordata">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <p>TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
.ckeditordata :first-child {
    margin top:15px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.selector> *:nth-child(1) {
  color: green;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <p>TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use through jQuery also. Check this code, if it works:

```
$('.ckeditordata').children(':nth-child(1)').css('margin-top','15px');
```

Comment: This can be done through pure CSS. OP has not even tagged jQuery and so what's the point in giving a jQuery option? I can understand if it wasn't possible with CSS.